# Fail to login to community with SAML JIT - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: community, saml

I try to setup SAML based SSO for a community.

I am basically following this instructions https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000198728&language=en_US and using Axiom tester ( Axiom single sign on tools - cant post link because of low reputation )

But when I click "login" button on Axiom final page i am displayed Salesforce login page and it says "To access this page, you have to log in to xxxxxxxx".

I checked the network data in the browser and I see that the endpoint where the saml assertion is posted returns "401 Unauthorized".

By the way this url is https://xxxxxxxxxx.ap2.force.com/hozen/login?so=12B39123456eXYZ

I am also using JIT user provisioning.

Can't understand what is going on and why I am not able to get logged in with SAML.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

We had this happen to us recently and the solution was as follows:

> The SAML attribute `Account.Owner` value referenced a deactivated User
>   !

```
<Attribute Name="Account.Owner" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Owner">
            <AttributeValue>005R0000002UshX</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
```

Specifically, the attribute value `005R0000002UshX` was a deactivated user (we had switched to a different user but the IdP team never got the commo. Sigh.)

The `Account.Owner` has to be an active user and have CRUD access on Account as it becomes the `CreatedById` and `OwnerId` of any JIT-created Accounts. [See related SFSE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/150918/2602).

If active but does not have CRUD access, a different error results - `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY Api Exception: entity type cannot be inserted: Account`

Here are the relevant bits of the SAML assertion:

```
<Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:emailAddress">foo@bar.com</NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_2CAAAAVl1lXGQME8wUjAwMDAwMDAwMDA1AAAAzMYIMgcWJr1m4QSgPvlL9yROBUp0zOWZ6yHIf8zncqR6ryMQxyuBv-6gsqVTOSAUyP1lhgTtnmge0FjBUeLtQC0e6eUfhoIeShYWGo8E6PA-I8quqJCFicMonqs4fYyyU-QtrprWBK5vqRRzPwIazeydic-uTx397QEmDWSwS3GoraJYkBNpdoz07N1pbM99ESTcdsRnUN7Yv-P8Q1qT9FCAQAa8LqKByKKvvHvXIy-MtEaMk9xnS3sTo0JHYuukxg" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-09T21:03:45Z" Recipient="https://full-myorg.cs2.force.com/mycustomers/login?so=someOrgId"/>
    </SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
<Conditions NotBefore="2016-12-09T21:00:40Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-09T22:00:45Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://full-myorg.cs2.force.com/</Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
</Conditions>
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="User.Username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Username">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.FirstName">
        <AttributeValue>Fred</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.LastName">
        <AttributeValue>Foo</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Email">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.ProfileID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.ProfileID">
        <AttributeValue>00e15000001IvN5</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.Email">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.FirstName">
        <AttributeValue>Fred</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.LastName">
        <AttributeValue>Foo</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.AccountNumber" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.AccountNumber">
        <AttributeValue>36</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Name">
        <AttributeValue>Acme Corp.</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.Owner" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Owner">
        <AttributeValue>005R0000002UshX</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

Comment: @Tony  -- see this answer. Hope it helps

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me.  So, it seems like this should be chosen as the "Best Answer"