# Who is the createdBy User when SAML JIT creates Contact - Account - User in Communities

Tags: community, saml

When using SAML JIT  to provision Community Users, who is the CreatedBy user when JIT, upon not finding a match on `federationId` or contact Email, creates the `Contact - Account - User`?

Provisioning rules are governed by this sequence

Sequence of actions for JIT provisioning

> As documented in [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181155), when provisioning over SAML,
>   Salesforce first attempts to match the Federated ID to the Federation
>   ID field of a User record.
>
> If a User record with a matching Federation ID is found, the user is
>   authenticated, and all of the editable User fields specified in the
>   assertion are updated with the values assigned.  In addition, some of
>   the Contact and Account fields can be updated (e.g., the
>   Account.TickerSymbol field can be updated; Contact.LastName and
>   Contact.FirstName can be updated).
>
> If no matching User record is found, Salesforce searches all Contacts
>   for a match based on Email. If a matching Contact is found, Salesforce
>   **creates the User record** and updates the Contact fields specified.
>
> If no matching Contact record is found, Salesforce searches for a
>   matching Account by Account.Name or Account.AccountNumber.
>
> If a matching Account record is found, Salesforce **creates a new
>   Contact** on that Account with the last name and email address specified
>   and then creates a User record with the specified fields (1).
>
> If no matching Account is found, then Salesforce **creates the Account**
>   with the specified Name, AccountNumber, and Owner; **creates the Contact**
>   with the information specified (again, the Contact.Email attribute
>   must be unique across all Contacts on all Accounts); and **creates the
>   User** record (2).
>
> (1) The Contact.Email attribute value must be unique across all
>   Contact records on all Account records, or provisioning will fail.
>
> (2) The specified Account Owner must have a Role or provisioning will
>   fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing these values can aid in constructing work flows to alert your Community Management folks. For example:

- when an Account is created that could potentially be a variant spelling of an existing Account.

**Contact**

- The `createdBy` user is called `Automated Process` and is not clickable. SFDC uses this user [for certain automated actions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-do-I-see-changes-from-the-Automated-Process-user-in-my-org-s-Setup-Audit-Trail-or-elsewhere-in-my-org&language=en_US) that maintain the org

[image]

**User**

- The `createdby` user is also `Automated Process`

**Account**

- The `createdBy` user is the value of `Account.Owner` included on the SAML assertion (!?!)
- A side effect of this is that the Profile for the `Account.Owner` has to be able to insert and update Accounts. You can't use a Read-Only Profile (like I tried) as you'll get this error: `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY Api Exception: entity type cannot be inserted: Account`

  ```
  <AttributeStatement>
   <Attribute Name="User.Username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Username">
      <AttributeValue>foobar@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="User.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.FirstName">
      <AttributeValue>Foo</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="User.LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.LastName">
      <AttributeValue>Bar</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="User.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Email">
      <AttributeValue>foobar@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="User.ProfileID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.ProfileID">
      <AttributeValue>00e15000001IvN5</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Contact.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.Email">
      <AttributeValue>foobar@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Account.AccountNumber" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.AccountNumber">
      <AttributeValue>35</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Account.Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Name">
      <AttributeValue>FooBar Industries</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Account.Owner" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Owner">
      <AttributeValue>005R0000002UsYa</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
  </AttributeStatement>
  ```